# Coin flipping Expected value and Probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider the following game:

- A game costs €100.
- A balanced coin is tossed.
- If it comes up HEADS, the game ends.
- If it's TAILS :
- The player receives a bonus (initially 1€).
- The next bonus is doubled (2€, 4€, etc.).
- Raise the coin as long as it's TAILS.

eg. TAILS - TAILS - TAILS - HEADS => -100 + 1 + 2 + 4 = -93

Questions :

- What is the player's expected payout?
- What is the smallest number of games the player has to play for the probability of winning to be greater than 1/2?

Comment: The expected value is $\mathbb E(X)=-100+\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} 2^{x}\cdot 0.5^x$

Comment: The probability of winning a net positive amount is $2^{-7} = 0.0078125$ which is not greater than $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This game is referred to as the "St. Petersburg Paradox". See this wiki for a full explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Answer (score 0):

This set-up is similar to the lottery game considered by Bernoulli. The expected payout is infinity. That is because the sum of the expected payout under all lengths of the game is always a sum of ones:
$$
-100 + \sum_1^{\infty} 2^i \cdot \frac{1}{2^i} = -100 +\sum_1^\infty 1 = \infty.
$$
For your second question, you should clarify what 'winning' is supposed to be. Is it to end up with a positive net payout? In that case, find $i$ such that the partial sum exceeds 100. That should be something you can easily do. (You must win $1$ how many times for you to justify paying 100?)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to write a program that calculates the probability of making a net profit as a function of the number of games played. Unfortunately, memory fails after 1000 games... The graph looks very strange and, according to my calculations, it would take more than 10^50 games to reach 50% equity. Does this sound plausible?

[image]